# Input Validation regarding integers corresponding to days of the week

Tags: java

I have been reading through Java documentation, but I cannot really seem to find a solution. My program asks for a number of 1-7 corresponding to a day of the week. I want the program to return an error "Sorry, not a valid number" when they enter a wrong number, such as 8,9,20 etc (since they do not correspond to a specific day of the week) My method is not working, any input?

```
while (!stdln.hasNextInt(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, not a valid number.");
    stdln.next();
}
```

I tried

```
while (dayOfTheWeek > 7) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, try again");
    stdln.next();
}
```

But this gets me stuck in a loop

Comment: Your latter attempt will never work, as it does not modify the dayOfTheWeek variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want. It will get an `int` from the user and report when the `int` out of range. You need to add a terminating condition that will break the loop or it will run until you terminat the application:

```
while (stdIn.hasNextInt()) {
    dayOfTheWeek = stdIn.nextInt();
    if (dayOfTheWeek == 0) {
        System.out.println("Zero was entered. Exiting");
        break;
    }
    if (dayOfTheWeek < 1 || dayOfTheWeek > 7) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, not a valid number.");
    }
    // do something else with dayOfTheWeek
}
```

This method call in your code is invalid. This method doesn't take 7 integers as arguments :

```
stdln.hasNextInt(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Also keep in mind that `next()` method will get every char you input including new lines. You will also have to assign the result of `next` to a variable for it to be any use.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this gives me: WorkHours.java:24: error: variable dayOfTheWeek is already defined in method main(String[])

Comment: @IronCoder31 Right. Then just assign to `dayOfTheWeek` instead of defining. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you but now when I execute the program it does not skip to the next section. I am completely drawing a blank on how to end the loop

Comment: Zero seems like a good invalid value to end the loop. Changed the code in my answer for you.

Comment: Okay I understand, but I don't want to exit the program if the wrong value is entered. I want it to go to the next question, "are you sick"? How do I make it jump out of the loop to the next section? I hope I worded this properly, thanks

Comment: `break;` will do precisely that : "jump" out of the loop. change the printed message to anything you like